# Querying within arrays

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a bunch of documents in my rethinkdb that look like this.

```
[
    {
        "complete": false,
        "blobs": [
            {
                "base64": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                "fingerprint": "123",
                "data": {
                    "meta1": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Serial Number": 123456,
                    "hash": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                    "meta2": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Info:": {
                        "length": 1024
                    },
                    "Validity": {
                        "begin": "20280801235959Z",
                        "end": "19960129000000Z"
                    },
                    "Version": 0,
                    "item count:": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "base64": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                "fingerprint": "456",
                "data": {
                    "meta1": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Serial Number": 123456,
                    "hash": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                    "meta2": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Info:": {
                        "length": 1024
                    },
                    "Validity": {
                        "begin": "20280801235959Z",
                        "end": "19960129000000Z"
                    },
                    "Version": 0,
                    "item count:": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "base64": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                "fingerprint": "789",
                "data": {
                    "meta1": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Serial Number": 123456,
                    "hash": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                    "meta2": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Info:": {
                        "length": 1024
                    },
                    "Validity": {
                        "begin": "20280801235959Z",
                        "end": "19960129000000Z"
                    },
                    "Version": 0,
                    "item count:": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "base64": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                "fingerprint": "101112",
                "data": {
                    "meta1": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Serial Number": 123456,
                    "hash": "MIICPDCCAaUCEHC65B0Q2Sk0tjjKe",
                    "meta2": {
                        "a": "abc",
                        "b": "bcd",
                        "c": "cdf"
                    },
                    "Info:": {
                        "length": 1024
                    },
                    "Validity": {
                        "begin": "20280801235959Z",
                        "end": "19960129000000Z"
                    },
                    "Version": 0,
                    "item count:": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "port": 443,
        "items": [
            {
                "blobs": [
                    "123",
                    "457",
                    "789",
                    "10112"
                ]}
        ],
        "secure": true,
        "fast": true
    }
]
```

Each document contains several "blobs". I need to query all of the blobs in all of the documents and return the "blob" that matches the fingerprint. I'm struggling to figure out how this should look.

I tried this query but returns all documents.

```
r.db('db').table('data').filter(r.row('blobs').contains(function(product) {
return product('fingerprint').eq('742c3192e607e424eb4549542be1bbc53e6174e2');
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
table.concatMap(function(row) { return row('blobs'); }).filter(function(blob) {
  return blob('fingerprint').eq('742c3192e607e424eb4549542be1bbc53e6174e2');
})
```

Comment: Yes I think it does, thanks. However, Im a little more confused now since this (https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5793) suggest I don't need the `concatMap` and suggests that `pathspecs` are way easier. The given `pathspec` example doesn't work though.

Comment: If you want multiple output rows from a single input row, you always need `concatMap` for that.